# php phalcon controller default to index

Tags: php, phalcon

Currently running Phalcon 1.0.0 since the latest is seg faulting for me. My problem is the routing that directs uri to a specific controller isn't working the way i would expect when adding ? to uri. In the example below, I expect uri /explore/?a=b to go to the Explore controller but it doesn't.

uri: /explore/       goes to ExploreController -> indexAction
uri: /explore/?a=b   goes to IndexController -> indexACtion

So, my question is there a way to force this without setting up entries in Phalcon\Mvc\Router add method? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It seems there is something misconfigured, that depends on what route URI data is actually passed to the router. Check this: http://phalconphp.com/documentation/index?a=1 and http://phalconphp.com/documentation/index, shows the same view

Comment: yes, i screwed up my nginx virtual host      
fastcgi_index   /index.php;
to 
fastcgi_index   index.php;

and now everything works correctly.

Comment: @user1973314 write that as your answer (you can answer your own questions) so that this one does not linger on as unanswered.